# How to integrate lush with j2me Polish 2.1.4

Tags: java, java-me, j2mepolish

I am working on j2me polish 2.1.4 and I want to use LUSH UI for symbian mobile application development. I could not find anything in my current version of j2me polish.

When I use the css from the website (http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/lush-ui/visual-guide-to-backgrounds/gui-background-partial.html) it gives me the following error:

```
D:\Mobile development\rising\build.xml:87: Invalid CSS: The CSS setting "type: horizontal-gradient;" is not supported. Please check style "recordbg" in your "polish.css" file(s).
BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 seconds).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer of my own question.

Actually Lush UI is already integrated into J2me Polish and I was doing a mistake, I was using nested property of CSS for the main property so I was receiving this error.